# redirecting a single https page to another http page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a old `https` page to new `http` page. I’ve tried this rule several times but it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^https://www.mydomain.com/tc/page.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Any one know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is this:

```
RewriteRule ^https://www.mydomain.com/tc/page.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Change it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^tc/page.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Also make sure `RewriteEngine` is set to `On` & there is a `https` check as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^tc/page.html$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

The issue is when you attempt to match `https://www.mydomain.com/tc/page.html` it will try to match your domain on top of that specific path like this:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/https://www.mydomain.com/tc/page.html
```

Which is incorrect since that would never exist.

Also,while I am not clear on what your desktop environment is, it’s generally best to not trust browsers at first when testing stuff like this.  I highly recommend using `curl` with the `-I` option to return the headers of a request to fully test it uncached & away from browser quirks like this.

For example, I tested this rule on my local Mac OS X MAMP setup like this:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8888/tc/page.html
```

And the `curl -I` output returned is:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 02:08:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
Location: http://www.mydomain.com/index.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The `Location:` field confirms this rule works as expected.

Comment: I believe you need to add `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` condition to your rule.